# Eclipse how to import a jar file as a maven project

Tags: java, eclipse, import, eclipse-plugin, m2e

I have downloaded a source jar file of OrientDB from maven repo, orientdb-source.jar. The structure is:

```
orientdb-source.jar/com/orienttechnologies/orient/core/...
                   /META-INF/...
```

I have installed m2e plugin. But I dont know to import this jar file as a maven project. I dont want to import this jar file as an external jar. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Did you solve the problem with depencencie @Li'?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to use/access this artifact within a maven environment.

If all you want to do is use the jar in your class path you should add the jar as a dependency in your project's pom file.  You may also need to add the repository reference to the pom if the jar is coming from a private repository.  Once your pom file is modified with the reference to the jar then you can select your project and click "Maven -> Update project dependencies".  Maven will download the jar and modify your class path.

If you want to actually look at the source then look for a reference on the 3rd party's web site to the repository containing the source code.  Use the appropriate Eclipse plugin (git, svn, etc.) to point to and checkout the version of the source.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to import the jar on your project, put this on your `<dependecies>` tag in pom.xml on root of your project:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.orientechnologies</groupId>
    <artifactId>orientdb</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

From [Maven Repository](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.orientechnologies/orientdb/1.3.0)

This will import the jar on your project lib folder.

Anyway, if you want to modify code from this lib, you need to create a new Project with content of this jar. Package as jar on maven and put as dependencie.